# Orchard - how to make a page work with querystring params?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-routing

I created a page like this in one of my modules - /OrchardLocal/Module1/Controller1/Action1. It takes an id parameter.

The page works if the id is passed like this - /OrchardLocal/Module1/Controller1/Action1/7

But I get an error if I pass the id in querystring - /OrchardLocal/Module1/Controller1/Action1?id=7

"The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'id' of non-nullable type 'System.Int32'"

I don't have to use querystring. But I would like to know why it is not working and how can I make it work with querystring.

Thanks

[EDIT]

Here is the action method.

```
    public ActionResult Action1(int id)
    {
        ...
    }
```

This is what I have in Routes.cs.

```
new RouteDescriptor { 
    Priority = 6,
    Route = new Route("Action1/{id}",
    new RouteValueDictionary{{"area", "Module1"},{"controller","Controller1"},{"action","Action1"}}, 
    new RouteValueDictionary(),
    new RouteValueDictionary{{"area", "Module1"}},
    new MvcRouteHandler())
}
```

Comment: This is not an Orchard question, it's a generic ASP.NET MVC question. You should read more about routes and model binding.

Comment: Can you paste your routes, and method signature for your controller action?

Comment: Added the route and controller action.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a matter of routing, not Orchard. This should work if you set id param as optional:

```
Route = new Route(
    "Action1/{id}",
    new RouteValueDictionary {
        {"area", "MyModule"},
        {"controller", "Controller1"},
        {"action", "Action1"}
        , { "id", UrlParameter.Optional}
    },
    new RouteValueDictionary(),
    new RouteValueDictionary {{"area", "MyModule"}},
    new MvcRouteHandler()
)
```

Note: with priority 6 I can't repro your error. It could be because you are on an earlier version of Orchard. I'm on 1.4. With Priority = 100 I can repro your error, and then the above change fixes it.